# Handling Multi Step Form Play Framework

Tags: forms, playframework

I am currently developing a Java application with Play Framework 2.2

I need to develop a multi-step form for getting data from user and stores them in database
I have to store all data in database in a single transaction, so I have to pass each form's data to the next step.what method do you recommend to use in order to fulfill this requirement.

What do you think of storing them in Cache what are pros and cons? and if you suggest to store them in Cache could you please include a piece of code in your answer that shows how to retrieve data from a form in Cache

Comment: Why do you need to store all the data in a single transaction?

Comment: That's a new question not my answer, this is the requirement of the application

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you save the data after each step in a table, e.g. `semi_form_data` and then at the end of the process extract the data and store it in the desired table(s). The advantages would be the ability to "resume" the data entry later and the ability to do a full validation on the data before saving it for good. An example of this approach is a two-step "Sign up" form.